# How much of the Earth's heat is caused by the hot centre?

Tags: geophysics, temperature, core

What is the percentage of the Earth's warmth that the Earth's hot centre is responsible for? What would be the temperature of the atmosphere if the Earth's centre was 18° C (average temperature on the surface)?

Comment: partly relevant : http://i.imgur.com/wUb82yS.png

Comment: @shrey Could you please share the whole document

Comment: (around pg 221 ) -- http://elibrary.bsu.az/azad/new/2194.pdf

Comment: 0.03% per Wikipedia:    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth's_internal_heat_budget#Global_internal_heat_flow

Comment: Why ask such a what-if about an 18° C core?

Comment: @wogsland because that's the average temperature on the surface

Answer (score 4):

Given the insulating effect of 6370 km of rock (the average radius of the Earth) & its low thermal conductivity, if the temperature at the center of the earth was 18 °C it contribution to warming the atmosphere would be negligible.

The temperature at the center of the Earth is about [7000 °C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_gradient), while the average temperature of the surface is about [10 °C](http://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=MOD_LSTD_CLIM_M). So if the temperature at the Earth's center was 18 °C its contribution to the surface temperature would be exceedingly small.